# Usage of "aussetzen"

Tags: verb, usage, verb-usage

I was making fun of someone's funny picture, and as response got a comment of

> Willst du was aussetzen?

The two meanings of the verb are *suspend*, and *expose*.

Am I right in interpreting the comment as

> do you want to *remark* on something (in specific)?

Somehow I can not get the feeling of the usage of the verb in this case.

Comment: Rather "criticise" (in a negative way) in this context...

Comment: Note that the sentence as cited is wrong (probably due to a misunderstanding or misremembering). _Aussetzen_ in this meaning needs an _an_ (e.g. _Willst du was daran aussetzen?_), and even then it would be unusual; it is normally only used in the phrase _etw. an etw. auszusetzen haben_, as in the example in @Jan's answer. (Perhaps he can expand his answer a bit regarding this aspect.)

Comment: "Hast du was auszusetzen?" was the literal comment.

Comment: Feel free to edit the literal comment in instead of the *willst du …* version ;) You know where the edit button is, don't you? (Underneath the tags on the left)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word has multiple meanings, two of which you have covered with your translations.

- to miss a turn

  > Wer eine 1 würfelt, muss eine Runde **aussetzen**.
- to suspend, discontinue something

  > Das Gericht **setzte** den Beschluss **aus**.
- to expose

  > Der Einsiedler stieg aus seinem Erdloch und **setzte** sich dem Wetter aus.
- to set free

  > Der Hund wurde an der Raststätte **ausgesetzt** – im Hotel war kein Platz für ihn.
  >   Seit wir Fische im Teich **ausgesetzt** haben, ist das Algenwachstum stark zurückgegangen.
- and finally: to (negatively) criticise something

  > Ich habe an deinem Bild **auszusetzen**, dass es lächerlich wirkt.

Most of the connotations this word implies are negative; in fact, only the fish-sentence can be understood in a positive way. I’m pretty sure that most of the meanings derived from somehow *sitting something out* or *making something sit outside*; it is now a rather widespread verb that can carry dozens of subtle meanings in context.

Note that *etwas **an etwas** aussetzen* usually requires a complement with the particle *an* — not present in the OP’s quote. However, I have heard the occasional German omit that complement if both parties were absolutely sure about the object that was being criticised. Omitting *daran* is not formally correct, though.

Comment: I believe _criticize_ is too neutral in English (not equivalent to German _kritisieren_). Additionally, if I _habe etwas auszusetzen_, I do not necessarily say so. Dictionaries suggest _find fault with sth_.

Comment: Arguably, the first two meanings are actually the very same meaning in different contexts.